# how to set tabindex for django autocomplete?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-autocomplete-light

in my forms I have some fields (name, places and job). Places is a foreign key. so i used autocomplete for that field.

if I press tab after entering name the cursor moves to the autocomplete. after choosing the place when I press the tab key it moves to the search bar in the theme. i guess its because of the tab-index of autocomplete is -1.

Then for the second thoughts, if that's the reason the cursor wouldn't have moved to the autocomplete, right?

any way I gave that search input `tabindex = -2` . this time the cursor moved to the logo which is a link to the homepage then to the next a tag. After some more tabs I finally reached to the beginning of the form.

how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

**You have two options**

**1. Override the widget and provide an attribute dictionary in the django forms.**

```
name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex': 1})
```

A detailed instruction of setting custom attributes in django is available in the django documentaion. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

**2.Define a custom template filter that adds a tabindex attribute**

```
@register.filter
def tabindex(value, index):
    value.field.widget.attrs['tabindex'] = index
    return value
```

Then, add tabindex to the fields in the template. For example:

```
{{ form.first_name|tabindex:1 }}
{{ form.email|tabindex:3 }}
```

Comment: I gave the name input ```tabindex=1``` , place autocomplete  ```tabindex=2``` and job input ```tabindex=3```. now when I press tab after choosing an option from place, cursor moves to name input. because it has tabindex 1 where as the hidden select inside autocomplete has ```tabindex = -1```. but tabindex of autocomplete is 2 as I have given